# Absolute positioning of two inputs inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a fixed position on a page. It holds two inputs, but the inputs aren't equally spaced inside the div.

HTML

```
<div class="submit_content">
     <input class="btn" value="Cancel"/>
     <input class="btn" value="Save"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.submit_content {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10px;
}

.submit_content input {
    width: 30%;
    height: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

How do I make the two inputs inside the fixed div equally spaced? The [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jty6v/) shows them hovering closer to the left because i have the `margin-right` set. Otherwise the inputs would be immediately next to each other. They should be separated, but the spacing inside the div should still be equal

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through adding this css to your code:

**css**

```
 .submit_content input {
    width:30%;
    height:25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    }
```

See it work in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jty6v/1/).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. The right button also has a `margin-right`, thus (since the left button does not have a `margin-left` like the right button), they have a little different spacing.

To get rid of this issue, add this line:

```
.btn:last-child { margin-right:0; }
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Jty6v/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
.submit_content input.btn:last-child {
   margin-right:0 ;  
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U5Cz4/)